# Why does `(state == 1 && 3)` make sense?

Tags: javascript

I came across this code in `Mithril.js`:

```
finish(state == 1 && 3)
```

To my (Java/C programmer's) eyes it looks like it should always invoke `finish(true)` if `state` is `1` and `finish(false)` if `state` is not `1`. But it actually seems to do `finish(3)` for the former and `finish(false)` for the latter.

What is the logic behind this?

Is this idiomatic in JavaScript, or is it a bad idea? To me it's horribly obscure.

Comment: If state==1, the expression has a value of 3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a characteristic of JavaScript, && and || operators always return the last value it evaluated.

Comment: So it's the equivalent of `finish(state==1 ? 3 : false)`, which IMO is so much clearer? Does increasing familiarity with JavaScript reduce the obscurity of the OP idiom?

Comment: @LawrenceDol: yes, familiarity makes it clearer. Though `||` is used more often I think. Typically for defaulting values. (`a = a || 'default';` as first line of a function that takes `a` as parameter)

Answer (score 13):

You can interpret the operators `||` and `&&` like this:

```
    A || B
→   A ? A : B

    A && B
→   A ? B : A
```

But without evaluating `A` twice.

Answer (score 8):

In JavaScript, the `&&` operator doesn't force the result to a boolean. It's instead similar to:

```
var _temp = state == 1;
finish(_temp ? 3 : _temp);
```

Testing the *truthiness* of the left side, then returning either the right when *truthy* or the left otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

The comparison `a && b` actually returns the value the last value evaluated in the expression and not `true` or `false`.

You can refer to the [spec](http://es5.github.io/#x11.11):

> The production *LogicalANDExpression* : *LogicalANDExpression* &&
>   *BitwiseORExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *LogicalANDExpression*.
> 2. Let *lval* be GetValue(*lref*).
> 3. If ToBoolean(*lval*) is false, return *lval*.
> 4. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *BitwiseORExpression*.
> 5. Return GetValue(*rref*).