# Why does using && in Javascript not produce a boolean result?

Tags: javascript

I was expecting both of these to produce a boolean `true` or `false`

```js
if(Array.isArray(myarr)){}
```

```js
if(Array.isArray(myarr) && myarr.length){}
```

But it turns out the second result is actually the length of the array.

But && is a boolean operator, no? Why does the code not output a boolean?

```js
let myarr= [1,2];
let x = (Array.isArray(myarr) && myarr.length);
console.log(x); // 2
```

Comment: Maybe the same way `||` defers to the second argument of the first one is falsy?

Comment: → https://stackoverflow.com/a/26025220/416224

Comment: Also, https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-binary-logical-operators: "The value produced by a && or || operator is not necessarily of type Boolean. The value produced will always be the value of one of the two operand expressions."